# make command no target

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

I try to follow a instruction to build a linux kernel

```
alias makearm='make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-'
makearm defconfig
```

I thought defconfig is a target in Makefile. but it's not. defconfig is a file name. and there is no defconfig target in the Makefile.

defconfig is a file that define a list of variables

```
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY=y
CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT=16
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
CONFIG_MEMCG=y
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH=y
CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y
```

how the make works? where is the rules?
really confused.
thanks

Comment: There is a choice of several different *_defconfig files in arch/arm/configs/ , for example  if you want to use the foo_defconfig file, use `makearm foo_defconfig`.

Comment: There is nothing in this description that describes a problem to be solved.  If you are getting an error or whatever please be sure to cut and paste the exact message (not paraphrased!) into your question and format it as a code block so it's clear.  If you just want to learn about how to build the Linux kernel in general and how the makefiles work, StackOverflow is not the right place to ask about that.  You can see the documentation that comes with Linux or ask on a dedicated mailing list or group.

Comment: You can just type `make help` to list the targets.

Answer (score 0):

the problem I have is make commandline.

```
makearm defconfig
```

in Makefile, there is no target of defconfig. then I found a pattern target %config: in Makefile. it solved my problem.

Comment: Instead of posting a second answer, edit the one you posted before. (But it's unlikely that this will be useful to future visitors.)

Comment: I deleted 1st answer.